How to set Font Name (Not Font Size) in Drop Down List of a TextBox AutoComplete Mode
I need to set the Font SutonnyMJ(Bangla), it is ok for the TextBox, But when I use AutoCompleteMode of the TextBox, the DropDown list Font Name is not working. Font size is not my issue. My issue is Font Style (not english language)
Please help me.
Thanks

Share the code you have written.
